How to create a mockview (type LIstView) in UnitTest?
I have a simple action in the list view of my XAF application. The action's active (true/false) state is determined by the current view ID. I am trying to write a unit test for this action, but I am unable to create a mock view of my list view (e.g., "Employee_Custom_ListView"). How can I create a view for a given list view ID in a unit test?
Here is my code.
public partial class EmployeeListViewActionController : ViewController  
{  
private SimpleAction EmpAction;  
public EmployeeListViewActionController()  
{  
    InitializeComponent();  
    TargetObjectType = typeof(Employee);  

   {  
    EmpAction = new SimpleAction(this, "EmpAction", PredefinedCategory.Edit)  
    {  
        Caption = "EmpAction",  
        SelectionDependencyType = SelectionDependencyType.RequireMultipleObjects,  
        TargetViewType = ViewType.Any  
    };  
    EmpAction.Execute += EmpAction\_Execute;  
  }  
}

protected override void OnActivated()  
{  
  base.OnActivated();  
  ManageActionVisibility();  
}

public void ManageActionVisibility()  
{  
  if(View.Id == "Employee\_Custom\_ListView")  
  {  
    EmpAction.Active.SetItemValue("Action", true);  
  }  
  else if(View.Id == "Employee\_ListView")  
  {  
    EmpAction.Active.SetItemValue("Action", false);  
  }  
  else  
  {  
    // Other logic.  
  }  
}

private void EmpAction\_Execute(object sender, SimpleActionExecuteEventArgs e)  
{  
// Implementation..  
}

protected override void OnDeactivated()  
{  
    EmpAction.Active..Clear();  
    base.OnDeactivated();  
}

I am Using Mock to create ListView , So How can I create a view for a given list view ID in a unit test by using Mock.
I have created a mockview like below
     var mockView = new Mock<View>(/*isRoot:*/true);
     mockView.Setup(v =>v.ObjectSpace).Returns(objectSpaceMock.Object);

     var controller = new controller();
     controller.SetView(mockView.Object);

but in this case mockview created has null value as id.
tried to give id like this
controller.TargetViewId = "Employee_Custom_ListView";

but still the view id null
Any help would be appreciated.
